# Missing 'Show' Template in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, missing-template

I am getting an error message stating

> Missing template syndication/show, application/show with
>   {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:text], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb,
>   :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: *
>   "Projects/PlanoSyndication/app/views"

Here is my Route:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

    get 'syndication/:name', to: 'syndication#show', defaults: {format: 'txt'}

end
```

Here is my model:

```
class Syndication < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Here is my Controller:

```
class SyndicationController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @syndications = Syndication.find_by name: 'tour_urls.txt'
  end

end
```

and in `views/syndication/show.html.erb` sits

```
<div>
  <%= @syndications.each do |syn| %>
    <%= syn.body %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  This is a very simple problem, I am just having real trouble finding it.

Comment: How did `format: :txt` get in there in the first place?

Comment: If you include `format: :txt`, Rails will only look for .txt files, and your file is a `.html.erb`, which is `format: :html`, and that's the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's the `defaults: {format: 'txt'}` option that's causing the lookup to fail.

You can see in this error:

```
Missing template syndication/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:text], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "Projects/PlanoSyndication/app/views"
```

That the "formats" list doesn't contain `html`. You could remove the `defaults` option and the lookup should succeed if your files are placed & named correctly.

Answer (score 0):

NO need to have defaults: {format: 'txt'} in your routes.rb